# Azure Cosmos DB stored procedure not returning documents

Tags: azure, stored-procedures, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to create a stored procedure in Azure Cosmos DB using node.js. Creating the stored procedure is successful, but when trying to execute it (from javascript/nodejs), it returns no documents.

First, I define the stored procedure and then register it in Cosmos DB:

```js
var DocumentDBClient = require('documentdb').DocumentClient;

var host = "our-hostname";  // Add your endpoint
var masterKey = "our-master-key"; // Add the masterkey of the endpoint

var client = new DocumentDBClient(host, {masterKey: masterKey});

var powerPlantDataReadingStoredProc = {
    id: "GetPowerPlantDataReadingsSproc",
    serverScript: function() {           
        var context = getContext();           
        var collection = context.getCollection();   
        var request = context.getRequest();
        var response = context.getResponse();

        var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(collection.getSelfLink(),
                    'SELECT TOP 1 * FROM c',
                    function(err, feed, options) {
                        response.setBody(JSON.stringify(feed));
                    });

        if(!isAccepted) throw new Error("The query was not acceted by the server");
     }
};

// Register stored proc
var createdStoredProc;

client.createStoredProcedure('dbs/PowerPlantDataReadings/colls/DataReadings', powerPlantDataReadingStoredProc, function(err, sproc) {
    createdStoredProc = sproc;
});
```

And the code I'm using for executing it:

```js
client.executeStoredProcedure("dbs/PowerPlantDataReadings/colls/DataReadings/sprocs/GetPowerPlantDataReadingsSproc", null,
    { partitionKey: "datareadings" },
    function(err, results, responseHeaders) {
        if(err) {
            console.log("Error: ");
            console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
        }

        if(responseHeaders) {
            console.log("Headers: ");
            console.log(JSON.stringify(responseHeaders));
        }

        console.log("Results: " + results);

        if(results) {
            console.log("Results: ");
            console.log(JSON.stringify(results));
        }
    });
```

I'm getting no errors in the console. Just an empty array. Also, there **are** documents in the collection ;-)

Does anyone know what I'm missing here?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Getting these response headers from the sproc:

Headers: `{"cache-control":"no-store, no-cache","pragma":"no-cache","transfer-encoding":"chunked","content-type":"application/json","server":"Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0","strict-transport-security":"max-age=31536000","x-ms-last-state-change-utc":"Tue, 05 Sep 2017 08:01:38.741 GMT","x-ms-schemaversion":"1.3","x-ms-alt-content-path":"dbs/PowerPlantDataReadings/colls/DataReadings/sprocs/GetPowerPlantDataReadingsSproc","x-ms-content-path":"cjFwAKg0WQA=","x-ms-quorum-acked-lsn":"25347","x-ms-current-write-quorum":"3","x-ms-current-replica-set-size":"4","x-ms-xp-role":"1","x-ms-request-charge":"6.12","x-ms-serviceversion":"version=1.14.89.5","x-ms-activity-id":"604b8d09-ad08-427a-8dee-1b7862e0e092","x-ms-session-token":"0:25347","x-ms-gatewayversion":"version=1.14.89.5","date":"Tue, 05 Sep 2017 09:38:32 GMT","x-ms-throttle-retry-count":0,"x-ms-throttle-retry-wait-time-ms":0}`

Results: `[]`

Also, when making the query in the query editor on Azure Portal, I do get a result as expected:

[image]

My partition key is as follows:

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't `serverScript` attribute name be `body` in your code?

Comment: @GauravMantri hmm, not according to this article, it seems? :-) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/programming

Comment: Mine was based on this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/create-a-stored-procedure. In fact we're using Node SDK and we use `body` attribute to specify function body.

Comment: @GauravMantri thanks! Just tried to name the attribute `body` instead of `serverScript`, but it made no difference :-/ No errors at all, but no results either

Comment: Thing is, if I just do `response.setBody("Hello World")` it returns fine, so maybe it's because of the query logic

Comment: A few things: 1) When you execute this query through some other place (Query Explorer in portal for example), do you see any data? 2) Can you edit your question and include response headers? It could very well be that you're getting continuation token and no documents.

Comment: @GauravMantri sure, I just updated my post now :-) Getting a result fine when querying directly in Azure portal

Comment: One more thing: I am able to reproduce this behavior if I specify an incorrect partition key value when executing stored procedure.

Comment: @GauravMantri I think it is a partitioned collection, yes. Not exactly sure where I can check that, but I've got a partition key: `/datareadings`, so I guess it's partitioned?

Comment: It is indeed a partitioned collection. I noticed that you're specifying the attribute's name in `partitionKey` property. You would need to specify the value there. So `{ partitionKey: "datareadings" }` needs to be changed to `{ partitionKey: "actual-partition-key-value" }`. Please give this a try.

Comment: @GauravMantri hmm, but I do think my partition key is `datareadings` ? :-) Just updated my post with a screenshot from my collections settings, where the partition key is stored in Azure Portal

Comment: `but I do think my partition key is datareadings` --> That is the name of partition key attribute. What you need to specify is its value i.e. the actual data held by this attribute.

Comment: I seems to be able to reproduce this problem. Weird

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting the Partition Key to the actual value? this worked for me. I was giving my partition key name to the stored procedure input but I actually gave it a partition key VALUE (because stored procedures operate on specific partitions) and it worked.

EDIT:

Just looked at the comments and Gaurav seemed to have suggested this approach as well

Comment: Could you expand on your original comment a little? I think I might be running into this, trying to pass my partition key in in the portal and can't get any results.